# php script not receiving file properly

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web-services

I have a webpage to submit a pdf to a back end script for processing. The page sends the file to the php script with ajax like so:

```
function sendFile(event)
    {
        $("#submitForm").hide();
        var formData = new FormData();
        var file=$("#journal")[0].files[0];
        formData.append("document", file);
        $.ajax({url:"converter.php", 
           data:formData, 
           contentType:false, 
           processData:false, 
           dataType:"text", 
           type:"post",
           success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            //miscellaneous code
        } });
    }
```

and it works, but when I try to access `$_POST['document']` I get:

> **Notice:** Undefined index: document

Anyone know what's wrong?

edit: the output of var_export($_POST) is an empty array

Comment: Can you post the output of `var_export($_POST)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need pass form object which contains your selected file to construct formData() as a parameter

`var fData = new formData($(#formId))`